# Conditionally referencing values from one sheet to another in excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-statements, worksheet

I have an excel workbook with various sheets of data and I am trying to write a formula that populates the information from one sheet TVUPDATED into another one TVUPDATED2.

The issue is that the TVUPDATED is regularly updated and when it is, the order of the table changes. The table size is 12x16 (RXC) with headers and the first 2 on the columns on the far-most left contain the two Identifier tags/categorical variables that distinguish all numerical values in the cells to the right of them. There are only 2 different tags in the first column and 6 in the second with a (11 unique combinations total).

Given that the order of the table in TVUPDATED is always changing, could anyone suggest some VBA code or an excel formula I could use to get value(s) from the table into a specific cell in TVUPDATED

I tried my hand at doing this with VBA:

```
Sub formular()

Dim name As Range
Dim produce As Range
Dim TV As Worksheet
Dim TV_UPDATED Worksheet
Dim TV_UPDATED2 As Worksheet
Dim Wokbuk As Workbook


Set Wokbuk = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx")
Set TV = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx").Worksheets("TV Summary")
Set TV_UPDATED = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx").Worksheets("U1")
Set TV_UPDATED2 = Workbooks("BookofWok.xlsx").Worksheets("U2")

For Each name In TV.Range("a2:a12")
    If name.Value = "reezy plc" Then
        For Each produce In TV.Range("b2:b12")
            If produce.Value = "duce1" Then
                TV_UPDATED.Range("D4") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce2" Then
                TV_UPDATED.Range("D6") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce3" Then
                TV_UPDATED.Range("D7") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce4" Then
                TV_UPDATED.Range("D8") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            End If
    Next produce
    Elseif name.value = "yung plc" Then
        For Each produce In U2.Range("b2:b12")
            If produce.Value = "duce1" Then
                TV_UPDATED2.Range("D4") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce2" Then
                TV_UPDATED2.Range("D6") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce3" Then
                TV_UPDATED2.Range("D7") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "duce4" Then
                TV_UPDATED2 .Range("D8") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            Elseif produce.value = "" Then
                TV_UPDATED2.Range("D9") = produce.Address().Offset(0, 1)
            End If

        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Are the Headers you need always the same (always the same string)? If yes, are they always on the same row? How many such headers must be identified, in order to find out their column? Is it something else, then the header column, needed?

Comment: @FaneDuru Headers needed are always the same in the same row in the same column (A and B). Two of these headers must be identified, but the data within these columns is always changing order. I've edited the code, so it should make more sens now hopefully.

Comment: I never try to deduce your logic to be applied from a code not working as expected! Can you explain (in words) what logic must be applied, in order to obtain what you need?

Comment: Within a workbook, I'm trying to reference data values from mastersheet , into two different sheets: sheet A and B. The data is an array/table the first two columns of which contain string values. there are only two distinct string values in column A and 6 in column B. Referencing is from the master sheet is based on the unique pairings between column A and B, for each pairing there is a different value in column C, and the value in column C is what is what I need referenced into sheets A and B. Hope that makes sense @FaneDuru .

Comment: I still do not understand what you need! Maybe my English is not accurate enough... I wish you a good day!